# iPhone application Problem with class view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In my application i have a nib file (view A) containing some textFields. In front of date textField i have put button pressing which takes to the calendar view. I used the code

```
-(IBAction)cal:(id)sender
{
    CalendarTestViewController *calander1=[[CalendarTestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:calander1 animated:NO ];
    [calander1 release];
}
```

That is fine.It takes me to calendar view and in calendar view i have wrote the code so that when somebody tap a date it will automatically move to previous view i.e. view A. Then when somebody press a button in A , which takes you confirmation view(another class).It flush all data in textFields.

I was wondering rather then using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:calander1 animated:NO ];
```

is there any other way to accomplish this behaviour. i want to save my data for confirmation view.

This is my calendar View tap tile method.

```
- (void)calendarView:(KLCalendarView *)calendarView tappedTile:(KLTile *)aTile
{
    // NSLog(@"Date Selected is %@",[aTile date]);

    if (cat==nil) {
        cat=[[FormController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        NSString *st=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[aTile date]];
        cat.mas=st;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:cat animated:YES];
        [cat release];

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
}
```

after pressing any time from calendar i want to fill date on textField n return to the previous view
I dont want to put this calendar view in navigation stack.

---

After some changes : below is my CalendarTestViewController.m file's tap tile method.

```
- (void)calendarView:(KLCalendarView *)calendarView tappedTile:(KLTile *)aTile
{
    // NSLog(@"Date Selected is %@",[aTile date]);

    if (cat==nil) {
        cat=[[FormController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        NSString *st=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[aTile date]];
        cat.mas=st;

        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:cat animated:YES];
        //[cat release];

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
}
```

FormController.m

```
- (void)calendarDidSelectDate:(NSDate *)selectedDate
{
    cali.text=mas;
    // set the selectedDate wherever it needs to be...
}


-(IBAction)cal:(id)sender
{
    CalendarTestViewController *calendar1=[[CalendarTestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    calendar1.delegate = self;

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:calendar1 animated:YES];

}
```

I have done exactily the same as suggested means protocols and delegate defined same way. no error shown but date is not selected and not filled in label.text in formController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:calander1 animated:YES];
```

This will bring your calendar view from bottom by default. If you want it to cross-fade you can set:

```
calendar1.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
```

or you can have it flip by setting:

```
calendar1.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

You need to call this setter before presenting the view controller btw. Also, presenting this calendar view controller modally means you have to dismiss it modally instead of popping it from navigationController.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**Edit**

To give the selected date back to your FormController, you need to declare a delegate protocol inside your CalendarTestViewController.h

```
@protocol CalendarTestViewControllerDelegate

- (void)calendarDidSelectDate:(NSDate *)selectedDate;

@end
```

This tells your compiler that the delegate will have to implement method named calendarDidSelectDate:

Then you need to give your CalendarTestViewController a delegate property, also inside .h, right before the last @end

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<CalendarTestViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

This means you have a property of any class (that's what id stands for) that conforms to CalendarTestViewControllerDelegate protocol you declared above, and that property is called delegate. In your CalendarTestViewController.m file right under @impelementation line you have to put:

```
@synthetize delegate;
```

And now in your FormController.h at the line that says `@interface FormController : UITableViewController` you need to add `<CalendarTestViewControllerDelegate>` which tells the compiler this class will conform to that protocol. Now all that's left to do is in your `-(IBAction)cal:(id)sender` method add `calendar1.delegate = self;` and implement the delegate method somewhere inside FormController.m

```
- (void)calendarDidSelectDate:(NSDate *)selectedDate
{
    // set the selectedDate wherever it needs to be...
}
```

**Edit2**

You need to replace:

```
- (void)calendarView:(KLCalendarView *)calendarView tappedTile:(KLTile *)aTile{
// NSLog(@"Date Selected is %@",[aTile date]);

if (cat==nil) {
    cat=[[FormController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
      NSString *st=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[aTile date]];
    cat.mas=st;

  //  [self.navigationController pushViewController:cat animated:YES];
    //[cat release];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

with something like:

```
- (void)calendarView:(KLCalendarView *)calendarView tappedTile:(KLTile *)aTile
{
    [self.delegate calendarDidSelectDate:[aTile date]];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and:

```
- (void)calendarDidSelectDate:(NSDate *)selectedDate
{
    cali.text=mas;
    // set the selectedDate wherever it needs to be...
}
```

with:

```
- (void)calendarDidSelectDate:(NSDate *)selectedDate
{
    cali.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", selectedDate];
}
```

Comment: I  am agree with your suggestion. ok it will present my calendar view. but when i will select my date in calendar view i want to go back to my original view. so what shoould i do in that method

Comment: i have done same u suggested but now i cant select any date from my calendar view. it does not allow me simply nothing happens. i want when i select date it automatically fill textField data n gone away

Comment: As I said, when you pick a date in you calendar view, you should dismiss that view controller modally (look at the last line of code in my answer above). And about filling the text field...you need to fill the text field in your previous view with the selected date? Did you implement some kind of delegate method or notification, or do you need help with that too?

Comment: i have edited my question. Plz have a look on calendar view method

Comment: with your way it loads model view and dismiss. but now it does not allow me to select any date. why? it allowed to me in push view method way

Comment: It does select a date if it's dismissing, but you are pushing this "cat" object onto a navigationController that is no longer there. You should implement a delegate method to send your selected date back to the previous view controller, but that's for another question.

Comment: I got my calendar view on n off screen with model view controller but now i cant select date guys. i have written my code for calendar method in my question. plz help

Comment: Yes agree with u. how can i implement a delegate method to send selected date back to the previous view controller i.e. FormController? if you suggest me that will be great help mate. i really appriciate

Comment: i have shown specific  method for selecting a tile or date from calendar view

Comment: Edited my answer with complete delegate implementation and description, please accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: Yes let me try this. and thank u so much for your time anyway. i will accept your answer shortly

Comment: i have done exactly same. but still date is not filled into textField. i have modified my question and put code after your suggestion. plz have a look

Comment: We both forgot some stuff, I have updated my answer again (look after **Edit2**).

Comment: I did this thing as well. no error but date is not shown . in front of [self.delegate calendarDidSelectDate:[aTile date]]; warning shown "incompatible pointer type sending 'KLDate * ' to parameter of type 'NSDate *'"

Comment: This is getting too messy and it's getting too late here. You have the delegate method in which you get NSDate, you should be able to use that date and display it where you want to, I don't know where it is as I can't read your mind :)

Comment: Yes mate. its ok. anyway thanku so much for your efforts. you really an inteligent person. God bless u. if u want i will accept your answer

Comment: i have noted the method  - (void)calendarDidSelectDate:(NSString *)selectedDate
{
    
    cali.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", selectedDate];
 
  // cali.text=@"m";
    
    
    // set the selectedDate wherever it needs to be...
}
Does not working. because i tried to put cali.text=@"m"; in it simply it does not show anything. but when i put cali.text=@"m"; in viewWillApear method it shows m in label. so simply our method is not working

Comment: Where is this "cali" object defined? You can try to NSLog the date and you will see you're getting it, it's just that you're probably setting it to the wrong place.

Comment: Yes mate. i sorted. It was my fault. now i set t = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", selectedDate]; and then showed that t in viewWillApear method. Sorted. You are the best. Thanku so much

Comment: Actually i had confusion about protocols. u helped me to understand them as well. really thankful to you.

Comment: Just last simple question mate.i have taken this calendar project from somewhere else. obviously that is open source. i used it in my application. when i will submit my application to apple store ,will the object that?

Comment: Apple has no problem with open source, they even use a lot of open source in their own software http://www.apple.com/opensource

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIActionSheet` to show up a calendar view or a `UIPickerView` inside a UIActionSheet. This will take up half the screen and you can add it to the view using

```
[myActionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

If you do not like it you can just  show a `modalViewController` and dismiss it after a date is chosen.

Comment: Ok i will look both of the concepts but will it work with my calendar as well. Means in calendar class ,in method which deals with taping of date and returning to the previous view?

Comment: He has a custom view for calendar so UIPickerView (or more specifically UIDatePicker) is not really an option, and UIActionSheet is definitely not an option. Presenting that view controller modally sounds like the only right way other than pushing it onto navigation controller.